# Is 'analyze A into B' grammatically right?

Tags: grammaticality

Is 'analyze A into B' grammatically right?

For example, if I say

"I am trying to analyze that movie into two different parts"

Is the sentence grammatically right?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use it; perhaps the term "break down (into)" or "interpret (as)" is better for when you're talking about splitting something.

> I tried to analyse the movie by breaking it into two parts.
>
> I tried to analyse the movie by interpreting it as two parts.

Cheers

Comment: I disagree with "interpret," but I think "break down" or just "split" work fine.

Comment: Interpet isn't a synonem but can be used if needed. (Interpret the film as two parts). I chose it because it conveys the meaning of analyze with actually mentioning the extra verb for the splitting.

Comment: "Interpret as" seems good. I thought you meant "interpret into"

Answer (score 0):

### Main Answer

Your example sentence would sound incorrect to most English speakers.

The problem is that the sentence is trying to say **two** things about what you are doing, but only using **one** verb.

I will explain by turning your sentence into a conversation with two parts:

> Person: "**What** are you trying to do?"
>
> You: "I am trying to **analyze** the movie."
>
> *(The verb for this part is "analyze".)*
>
> …
>
> Person: "**How** are you trying to analyze the movie?"
>
> You: "I am **splitting** the movie **into** two parts."
>
> *(The verb for this part is "split … into".)*

The two parts can be combined back into one sentence with "by" as a joining word:

"I am trying to analyse the movie by splitting it into two parts."

---

### Comments and Extra Detail

Did you notice that I used a sentence just like your sentence in my answer?

It was this one:

> "I will **explain** by **turning** your sentence **into** a conversation with two parts."

My two verbs were "explain" and "turn … into".

---

Your sentence was very close to natural-sounding English.

- You were correct that "analyze" was a good verb to choose for talking about what you are doing to the movie.
- You were correct that "into" was a good choice for the second part of the **phrasal verb** for talking about how you were trying to analyse the movie.

---

English has lots of phrasal verbs ending with "into" that could have been used:

- split … into

"Split the movie into two parts."

- break … into

"Break the movie into two parts."

- break … down into

"Break the movie down into two parts."

- divide … into

"Divide the movie into two parts."

---

"Analyze … into" would probably never sound right as a phrasal verb in English no matter what the sentence was.

"Into" suggests that something is being **changed** in some way.

"Analyze" doesn't suggest that something is changing *as a word on its own*. This is because it doesn't include any information about **how** you are doing the analysis. It is only when that extra detail is included that we can tell if something is being changed or not.

For example:
"I analyzed this rock yesterday."
- we have no idea if the rock was changed or not.

"I analyzed this rock yesterday by **looking** at it with a microscope and then **weighing** it."
- the rock was not changed.

"I analyzed this rock yesterday by **splitting** it **into** 3 pieces with a hammer and then measuring the places where it cracked."
- the rock was changed (**into** 3 rocks).